# Class to position a window on the screen

Tags: python, pyqt

I am new to Python and this is my fist Python class. I am using PyQt4 framework on Windows 7.

I don't know whether the few lines of code below is correctly written or not. I want to modify it further as:

1. In the arguments, I want to pass the name of another opened Window (.py) on the screen.
2. I will be passing the x-coord., y-coord. and the name of the window to position on the screen.

How to modify the code to fulfill these requirements?

**Edited Further**

```
class PositionWindow:
    def __init__(self, xCoord, yCoord, windowName, parent = None):
      self.x = xCoord
      self.y = yCoord
      self.wName = windowName;

      def center(self):
        screen = QtGui.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        size = self.geometry()
        self.move((screen.width()-size.width())/2, (screen.height()-size.height())/2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can't you just use `window.setGeometry(x_pos, y_pos, width, height)`? A class seem overkill in this case.

See [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setGeometry-2) for documentation.

Comment: I will try, what other modifications needed.

Comment: Corrected in my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662500/how-to-display-qlineedit-on-the-window

Comment: It is<br>
window.setGeometry(x_pos, y_pos, width, height)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use

```
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Program()
    gui.move(380, 170)
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

the gui.move() will position your application to the stated coordinates in the parenthesis