# How to display QLineEdit on the window?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I created a small window using PyQt4 and Pydev. The code is below:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore

# Create GUI object
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QtGui.QWidget()

widget.setGeometry(400,300,800,800) # Position window
widget.resize(450,250)  # Resize window

widget.setWindowTitle('Sample')   # Set Title of the window

Password = QtGui.QLineEdit()    # Input Box for password

widget.show()   # Display window

# Exit program
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I created the **Password LineEdit** box but how to show on the active window, which is represented by **widget**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
Password = QtGui.QLineEdit(widget)
```

This tells Qt that you want `widget` to be the parent of the `QLineEdit`. If you leave out the `widget`, then the `QLineEdit` has no parent, so it's not shown.

**Update:** To position child items in parent windows, you'll have to read up about layouts (I assume you want to do it properly, not as a toy/learning exercise). Any good PyQt book should be able to help, e.g. [this one](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html).

Comment: Thanks Vinay, it worked. But it is being displayed on the very top touching the Window title bar. How to set the position?